# Cordova error (ERROR building one of the platforms)

Tags: android, cordova, ant, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I have been building my phonegap app in node.js without any problem. Suddenly when I tried to build now, it is showing some error and apk is not getting created.

Here is the error :

```
C:\testapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant debug -f C:\testapp\platform
s\android\build.xml -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\testapp\platforms\android\cordova
\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: C:\testapp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit
code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Vaishakh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

I haven't tweaked any system settings/properties. I haven't changed or uninstalled anything. This happened suddenly. I tried restarting but it didn't work.

Comment: That's usually a Java build error. What do you see above the: 

`C:\testapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126`